# Test class(s) with Findbugs though findbugs object

Tags: java, unit-testing, findbugs

I want to use Findbugs through the code, to test another class by using findbug through coding.  I tried a lot but could not find a way to test class(s) though the coding.

Comment: Did you try the [tag:java-web-start] [demo](http://findbugs.cs.umd.edu/demo/jnlp/findbugs.jnlp)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your taskdef, use the classpath attribute to specify where exactly the jar that contains findbugs class (FindBugsTask) is located. Try something like this:

```
<taskdef name="findbugs" classpath="C:\apache-ant-1.7.1\lib\findbugsant\findbugs-ant.jar" classname="edu.umd.cs.findbugs.anttask.FindBugsTask" />
```

The findbugs jar I have is findbugs-ant.jar, so check this out in the proposed solution and use the findbugs filename that applies to your case, and you should be ok.